# How to enable scaling of InAppWebView in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter

```
`InAppWebView(
initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(url: WebUri("http://192.168.5.129:8082/")),
onWebViewCreated: (InAppWebViewController controller) {
// ...
},
initialSettings: InAppWebViewSettings(
supportZoom: true,
builtInZoomControls: true,
displayZoomControls: true,
),
)`
```

I have implemented an InAppWebView in my Flutter app and I want to enable pinch-to-zoom functionality on the web page. I have already set the initialSettings. However, I am still unable to perform pinch-to-zoom on the page.

Is there something wrong with my implementation? How can I enable pinch-to-zoom functionality with InAppWebView in Flutter?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Does this only happen to that specific web page or does it happen to other web pages as well?

Answer (score 0):

Use this package **flutter_inappwebview** [Link](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview)

```
InAppWebView(
        initialUrl: 'https://your_url.com', // Your URL here
        initialOptions: InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
          crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
            // Enable pinch-to-zoom
            gestureRecognizersEnabled: true,
          ),
        ),
      )
```

For samples check this link. [ReferenceLink](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview_examples)

Comment: Which version in flutter_inappwebview does the gestureRecognizersEnabled attribute correspond to?

Comment: flutter_inappwebview: ^5.7.2+3